# How to adjust the frequency and duration of billing agreements for Amazon Pay

Tags: amazon-pay, amazonsellercentral

I am integrating amazon pay for our non-profit that offers one-time, monthly, and yearly donation plants.

I looked around and was not able to find how we could set the duration ( how long should the billing agreement continue) or the frequency ( how often should the buyer be charged ). I am not even sure if this feature is available or if billing agreements are only monthly subscriptions.

When I use the sandbox and hit the amazon api with `GetBillingAgreementDetails`, I see the `TimePeriodEndDate` which is only one month after `TimeStartEndDate`. I assume this is the time frame that the billingAgreement runs for, but I could not find a way to alter that period in the documentation.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no duration or frequency that you can set for Billing Agreements. Instead, it is up to you to decide when and how much you want to charge a buyer for when necessary (requires the Billing Agreement to be valid of course, this is what the GetBillingAgreementDetails API call is being used for example).

For charging the buyer, you need to call [AuthorizeOnBillingAgreement](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-api/authorizeonbillingagreement.html) as described in [this step](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-automatic/request-authorization.html) of the integration guide.

The time periods that you are referring to are part of the [BillingAgreementLimits](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-api/billingagreementlimits.html) object and tell you the maximum amount and the remaining balance that you can charge the buyer for in the time period that is defined by TimeStartEndDate and TimePeriodEndDate. The period is a read-only field and set by the Amazon Pay API.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I need to make monthly AuthorizeOnBillingAgreement calls for monthly subscriptions and call it once a year for annual subscriptions? if so, is there a way to make the payments automatic?

Comment: That's correct. Amazon Pay isn't providing a subscription management, or similar service, but leaves it up to you to decide when you want to authorize and capture the payment.

Comment: thanks, if you know of a good subscription management implementation, I would appreciate it if you could share it with me.